# add last row n times to time indexed data frame whilst increasing date by 1 day each time

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Here is some sample code:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Date': ['2018-01-01', '2018-01-02'], 'M1': [1, 1]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

df.Timestamp = pd.to_datetime(df.Date, format='%Y-%m-%d')
df.index = df.Timestamp

new_data = pd.DataFrame(df[-1:].values, columns=df.columns)
df = df.append(new_data)
```

I would like to copy the last row of the data frame n=5 times (started this crudely at the end) but I would also like to increase the Date + index date by one day. I think this would require something along this lines:

```
df['DATE'] + pd.DateOffset(days=10)
```

Ultimately, the wants should take this shape using above's example:

```
data = {'Date': ['2018-01-01', '2018-01-02', '2018-01-03', '2018-01-04', '2018-01-05', '2018-01-06', '2018-01-07'], 'M1': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a new DataFrame with `pd.concat` and a `date_range`.

```
n = 5

v = pd.to_datetime(df.Date.values[-1])
df2 = pd.concat([df.iloc[[-1]]] * n).assign(
    Date=pd.date_range(v, v + pd.DateOffset(days=n), closed='right'))

df2
        Date  M1  Timestamp      index
1 2018-01-03   1 2018-01-02 2018-01-02
1 2018-01-04   1 2018-01-02 2018-01-02
1 2018-01-05   1 2018-01-02 2018-01-02
1 2018-01-06   1 2018-01-02 2018-01-02
1 2018-01-07   1 2018-01-02 2018-01-02
```

Assign this back to the original `df` using an additional `pd.concat` step.

```
df = pd.concat([df, df2])
```